# Method can only be called again if 5 seconds is passed

Tags: java

I have an aplication running and i kinda want to create a timeout, my method is called too many times in a small amount of time. i want to determine that the method can only be called again if 5 seconds is passed. How do i do that ?

Comment: You mean to say that After calling method next invocation can happen only after 5 second for same object ? could you please example if possible

Comment: Do you want to put a rate limit in the method or in the calling code? It'd be more natural to fix the caller, assuming you're the author of both.

Comment: use Thread.sleep(5000)

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra exact. if the method is called in the second 0, i want that it can only be called again when 5 seconds is passed (second 5).

Comment: @SeanF this would stop all my application. i want to stop the method call for a while, so it cannot be spammed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way without getting into threads and timers etc is to take the current time when you call the method and store it. On the next call you compare the new current time to the old. If 5 seconds have not passed, do nothing.

e.g.

```
long lastCall = 0;
void doSomething()
{
    long now = secondsSinceEpoch();
    if (lastCall == 0 || now-lastCall > 5)
    {
        // Do stuff
        // lastCall = now
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this can help you.

```java
private long timeMillions = 0;

    public void doSomething(){
        // if within 5 seconds
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeMillions + 5 * 1000){
            //retrun or do some thing else
            return;
        }else{
            // after 5 seconds
            timeMillions = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("do something");
        }
    }
```